# Perfectly wrapping a function

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to trace all my OpenGL calls. To that end, I have the following macro:

```
#define EXEC_OPENGL(NAME, ARGUMENTS) debugOpengl(TOSTRING(NAME), [](void) { return NAME ARGUMENTS; })

EXEC_OPENGL(glDoSomething, (1, 2, 3, 4));
```

And the `debugOpengl` function code is similar to this:

```
void debugOpengl(char const * name, std::function<void ()> const & exec)
{
    GLenum err;

    exec();

    while((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "OpenGL Error: " << name << " " << err << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename Ret>
Ret debugOpengl(char const * name, std::function<Ret ()> const & exec)
{
    GLenum err;

    auto ret = exec();

    while((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
        std::cerr << "OpenGL Error: " << name << " " << err << std::endl;

    return ret;
}
```

This code doesn't work, because (at least on GCC 7) when it comes to functions that return void, the lambda defined in the macro is invalid (because `void value not ignored as it ought to be`).

I also tried writing a template functor class, but it eventually was a pain and didn't work (my perfect forwarding failed to properly forward literal numbers).

What's a good way to simple execute something before and after calling a function, assuming I can wrap with a macro all the calls to it?

Comment: Lambda will never match a `std::function` in deduction. Your templated `debugOpengl` will never be called. In fact, it's always the first version being called.

Comment: @liliscent That makes sense. Is there another way to achieve the same result, possibly with a completely different implementation of the macro?

Comment: Specify the `Ret` type explicitly when calling it in macro.

Comment: You could try a different approach. OpenGL registry provides a complete parsable list of GL functions (with return and parameter types), so you can make your own GLEW-esque library, able to execute arbitrary code at calls. Also it will allow you to get rid of the ugly macro.

Comment: That's a bit extreme, and I'd prefer to find a C++ solution. Other use cases might come up for this kind of thing (like wrapping a library that doesn't offer parsable lists).

Comment: Trivially, can you use a separate macro to cover the `void` case?

Answer (score 1):

You might use RAII to display error:

```
template <typename F>
class Finally {
public:
    Finally(F f) : f{f} {}
    Finally(const Finally&) = delete;
    Finally& operator=(const Finally&) = delete;

    ~Finally() noexcept {
        try {
            f();
        } catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "Exception during stack unwinding" << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    F f;
};

template <typename F>
decltype(auto) debugOpengl(const char* name, F&& f)
{
    Finally finally{[name](){
        GLenum err;
        while((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        {
            std::cerr << "OpenGL Error: " << name << " " << err << std::endl;
        }
    }};
    return f();
}
```

Provided code uses C++17, but can be done in C++11

Comment: Using the dtor to invoke the logging function is clever.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GCC bug, [since fixed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kh9awCcljEleIRxj): a [lambda’s return type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is [deduced as `void`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction) if it returns an expression of that type.